# Definition: rng ideal versus algebra ideal in a non-unital $C^*$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, ideals, c-star-algebras, rngs

When I first moved into operator algebras, equipped with the basics of abstract algebra, I encountered the following definition of ideals:

> **Definition (algebra ideals).** A *left* (respectively, *right*) *ideal* in an algebra $A$ is a vector subspace $I$ of $A$ such that
>   $$ a\in A\quad\text{and}\quad b\in I \quad \implies\quad ab\in I\qquad\text{(respectively, $ba\in I$)}. $$
>   An *ideal* in $A$ is a vector subspace that is simultaneously a left and a right ideal in $A$.

(This definition is taken from Murphy's textbook *$C^*$-algebras and operator theory*. It should be noted that *algebra* in this case means *associative algebra over $\mathbb{C}$, not necessarily commutative or with unit*.)

To a large degree, mathematics is the art of making the right definitions, and it is intuitively clear to me that we want $I$ to be a subspace. Nevertheless, I can't help but wonder whether or not the above is equivalent to the notion of a rng ideal in $A$:

> **Definition (rng ideals).** A *left* (respectively, *right*) *rng ideal* in an algebra $A$ is an additive subgroup $I$ of $A$ such that
>   $$ a\in A\quad\text{and}\quad b\in I \quad \implies\quad ab\in I\qquad\text{(respectively, $ba\in I$)}. $$
>   A *rng ideal* in $A$ is an additive subgroup that is simultaneously a left and a right ideal in $A$.

(The only difference is that the subspace assumption is replaced by the weaker subgroup assumption.)

---

Now, if the algebra is unital, it is easy to show that these two notions coincide. Suppose that $I$ is, say, a left rng ideal, then for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and $b\in I$ we have $\lambda b = (\lambda 1)b \in I$. However, it is not immediately clear whether or not these definitions are equivalent if $A$ fails to be unital.

[This page in the Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Ideal) gives a pathological example showing that the definitions are not equivalent for general associative algebras (or even Banach algebras): if $ab = 0$ for all $a,b\in A$, then every additive subgroup is a rng ideal, but only the subspaces are algebra ideals. This answers part of my question.

However, since I'm primarily interested in $C^*$-algebras, the following question remains:

> **Question.** Are there examples of rng ideals in $C^*$-algebras that fail to be algebra ideals?

In this setting, the pathological example from before is ruled out, due to the identity $\lVert a^*a\rVert = \lVert a\rVert^2$.

Comment: Partial result: the closure of a (left/right/two-sided) rng ideal in a $C^*$-algebra is automatically a (left/right/two-sided) algebra ideal. (Use approximate units.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $A=c_0$ and let $I$ be the rng ideal generated by the sequence $s$ with $s_n=1/n$.  Explicitly, we can describe $I$ as the set of sequences of the form $as+ts$ where $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $t\in c_0$.  I claim that if $b\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$, then $bs\not\in I$, so $I$ is not an algebra ideal.  Indeed, if we had $bs=as+ts$, then $(b-a)s=ts$ where $b-a$ is some nonzero scalar.  Since each term of $s$ is nonzero, this can only be true if $t_n=b-a$ for all $n$, which contradicts the requirement that $t\in c_0$.

Comment: Good example, thanks!